# removeEventListener not returning Boolean value in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, sdk, coronasdk

The docs for Corona SDK suggest that removeEventListener should return a Boolean value of true if a listener was successfully removed. I have a table of display objects that I iterate through to remove listeners. I want to use the Boolean value to identify objects that still have a listener when I run through the loop. My code is as follows:

```
for i=1,3 do
    myTable[i]:addEventListener("touch", aFunction )
end
for i=1,#myTable do
  if ( myTable[i]:removeEventListener("touch", aFunction ) ) then
    print("exists!")
  else
    print("did not exist")
  end
end
```

This does not seem to work, even if all the elements in myTable still have the listener. Any ideas?

Comment: First of all you should use  `for i=1,#myTable do`. How do you remove objects from a table object? How do you figure out what is object's listener?

Comment: a bracket also missing from second line!

Comment: Sorry, those were both typos when I modified the code to make it more generic. But the problem still exists. When I add listeners to a table and then try to remove them as above, the if statement never returns positive.